# Is there an OCR API for Google glass?

Tags: google-glass

I just had an *amazing* idea for an app, but it requires transcribing written text to computer recognised text.

I know that with Google Translate for Android you can take a picture and select text and it make that into computer words, is that available for free use?

Comment: I am planning to work with OCR for Glass as well. Did you find a good solution for realtime OCR? I have experience with Vuforia's OCR and think about using that. But it could be done easier probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such API for Google Glass.  Perhaps Google will release something in the future, but as of now no such thing.
You can of course use any web api to send a picture to a web server where processing is done and results sent back to Glass.  Likewise native android code runs on Glass, so any existing android libs should work with Glass.